# I want to find how many movies have been made in every decade

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

Tried this but it shows `DECADE` column and every row is `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT ReleaseDate, COUNT (Title),
CASE
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN 2010 AND 2019 THEN '2010 - 2019'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 THEN '2000 - 2009'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 THEN '1990 - 1999'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989 THEN '1980 - 1989'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN 1970 AND 1979 THEN '1970 - 1979'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN 1960 AND 1969 THEN '1960 - 1969'
        END AS DECADE
FROM Film
GROUP BY ReleaseDate
```

Comment: I assume `ReleaseDate` is `datetime`?

Comment: If `ReleaseDate` is a date (and time) data type what "date" do you think 2010 is?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the decade with an integer division. So, not CASE statement is required, but you must GROUP BY decades

```sql
SELECT
    CONVERT(nvarchar(3), YEAR(ReleaseDate) / 10) + '0 - ' +
      CONVERT(nvarchar(3), YEAR(ReleaseDate) / 10) + '9' AS Decade,
    Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM Film
GROUP BY YEAR(ReleaseDate) / 10
ORDER BY YEAR(ReleaseDate) / 10
```

I assume that `ReleaseDate` has a `date` or `datetime` type.

The result will be something like this:

| Decade | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1990 - 1999 | 14 |
| 2000 - 2009 | 17 |
| 2010 - 2019 | 23 |
| 2020 - 2029 | 3 |

Example: If the date is `2012-08-17`, then `YEAR(ReleaseDate)` is `2012`, `2012 / 10` is `201`. We convert it to a `nvarchar(3)` -> `'201'` and add the string `'0 - '` which gives `'2010 - '`. Then we do the same again but add `'9'` instead to get `2019`. Result: `'2010 - 2019'`.

The advantage of this approach is that you get automatically all the decades stored in your db. When a new decade starts, you get it automatically without have to complement your CASE expression.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may want to use a CROSS APPLY so that you can reference the alias

FYI - Technically the decade begins 2001

**Example**

```
SELECT B.Decade
      ,COUNT(*),
FROM Film A
CROSS APPLY ( values (
                    CASE  WHEN year(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2019 THEN '2010 - 2019'
                          WHEN year(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 THEN '2000 - 2009'
                          WHEN Year(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 THEN '1990 - 1999'
                          WHEN year(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989 THEN '1980 - 1989'
                          WHEN year(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 1970 AND 1979 THEN '1970 - 1979'
                          WHEN year(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 1960 AND 1969 THEN '1960 - 1969'
                     END 
                     ) 
            ) B(Decade)
GROUP BY B.Decade
```

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing the issue might be in the format of timestamp, try using **YEAR()** on ReleaseDate like so

```
CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(ReleaseDate) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2019 THEN '2010 - 2019' 
    ...
    ...
END
```

Answer (score -2):

`ReleaseDate` seems to be a date, in which case you can use date ranges:

```
SELECT DECADE, COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT 
CASE
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '2010 - 2019'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2009-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '2000 - 2009'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '1990 - 1999'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1980-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1989-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '1980 - 1989'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1979-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '1970 - 1979'
        WHEN ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1960-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1969-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '1960 - 1969'
        END AS DECADE
FROM Film
) t
GROUP BY DECADE
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but you are not including all the months and days of the last year.

Comment: I suspect the `GROUP BY` is not what the OP wants here either if they want a count of how many movies/films were released in each decade; this will give one row per release date, not decade.

Comment: @Larnu that's a good point, thanks! I have edited my answer, ensured that decade is a subquery and grouped by its value to achieve the count.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks for the tip. I was editing the query in the question in order to make sure that the `BETWEEN` criteria will work. Last year (2021) or 2020 was not included into the question, maybe with a good reason, maybe not, I cannot determine this based on the scarce information I have about the problem, so I decided not to add a new group.

Comment: It's not about a specific year. The conditions should look like this: `ReleaseDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59.9999'`, i.e., you must include the whole December. You are only including the first fraction of a second of the 1st of January.